# VBA formatting strings

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

As of right now everything is red. I need everything after the colon to be black and not be Italic.

Comment: Can you please explain more about this range of characters that you want to change?

Comment: I have the string sCallOut, I assign it to oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font later in the block of code.

With the With Statement, I am changing the properties of that string to be all red, size 20, italics, and so forth. It is a sub title for a powerpoint slide.

However, I need "Action:" to have the properties shown above with my current With Statement and I need "[Insert Callout Here]" to be Corbel, not Italics, size 20, and black.

Comment: Is there a way I can select a range of characters from my string for this text box and change their properties without change the entire string?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to isolate the characters after the colon and set the colour as required:

EDIT: Forgot about the italic bit......

```
Sub test()

    sCallOut = "ACTION: [Insert Callout Here]"
    Set oShp = pptSld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 110, 100, 557.28, 94.32)
    oShp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sCallOut
    oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter

    With oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
       .Name = "Corbel"
       .Italic = msoTrue
       .Size = 20
       .Color.RGB = RGB(216, 3, 33)
       .Bold = msoTrue
    End With

    With oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        With .Characters(InStr(.Characters, ":") + 1, .Length).Font
            .Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Italic = msoFalse
        End With
    End With

    Set oShp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line to make the text black:

```
.Color.RGB = RGB(216, 3, 33)
```

And this line to remove italics:

```
.Italic = msoFasle
```

EDIT:

If you have the cell location, you can do this to the string later on:

```
With Cells(1, 1).Characters(9, 21).Font
     .Color = vbBlack
     .Italic = False
     .Name = "Corbel"
     .Size = 20
```

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213721(v=office.11).aspx) shows how to use Characters

EDIT:

To change part of the text for a text box, you can declare two variables containing strings formatted differently and append them to the textbox.

It will follow the form:

*MyTextBox.Value = MyStringVariable*

or in your case:

*MyTextBox.Value = MyStringVariable1 & MyStringVariable2*

Comment: He's talking about a textbox not a cell.

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder found the following:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("txtbox1")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Choisir: wefhweufhwef 344tr saefaefa" 'Entering some text'
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 5).Font 'Selecting some font and changing some settings
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
End Sub
```

I haven't managed to do it without selecting the textbox first (?? maybe someone can help, usually it isn't hard). You can enter your text with a string in which you figure out the position of the colon using

```
dim MyString as string
dim intColon as integer
Mystring = "cwsvws:wifvwhivw"
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = MyString
intColon = instr(MyString, ":")
```

And use this as the character count to plug in the macro recorder's code. Then you can format different blocks of text how you want.

```
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(intColon, 5).Font
             .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
             .Fill.Transparency = 0
             .Fill.Solid
             .Size = 11
             .Name = "+mn-lt"
End With
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is for normal textboxes, not ActiveX textboxes. With an activeX one, it would be easier (I think) and more straightforward.